# What happens if object of a verb refers to the passive subject?

Tags: prepositions, to-infinitive

I have a sentence:

> In this regard, two hypotheses were picked to study.

by which I mean *selection of two hypotheses was done to study [the two hypotheses again]*. As shown, *study* refers to *hypotheses* again. Is the statement above grammatically sound or should it be reworded to something like the following:

> In this regard, two hypotheses were picked **for** study.

? Any additional underlying grammatical comments would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could say:

> In this regard, two hypotheses were picked for study.

When you write:

> In this regard, two hypotheses were picked **to study**.

I am expecting an object for "study", which might not refer to your hypotheses. For example:

> In this regard, two hypotheses were picked **to study how Santa delivers all those presents**.

Making the verb intransitive fixes this:

> In this regard, two hypotheses were picked **to be studied**.